How to know whether bottom sheet is open or not?
How to know whether bottomSheet of the Scaffold is open or not through scaffoldKey?
Here's how the sheet is open:
scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(.....);

Newer versions of flutter have no encapsulated methods within scaffoldKey.currentState that can be used to decide whether it's open or not.

In Detail
If you need to check the code, go to that gist
or go to dart pad
BTW, i have 3 bottom sheets that are being presented. so, it's not good choise to observe the status of each one of them through PersistentBottomSheetController. instead i need to just know whether is that scaffold currently presenting a bottom sheet or not. btw again: mounted property didn't worked! because bottom sheet is considered a part of the scaffold.

And where you are trying to know its visibility ?

@Md.YeasinSheikh, exactly in the listener of a BlocConsumer, in which that bloc consumer is above that scaffold in the widget tree.

Can you include a minimal snippet on dartPad

@Md.YeasinSheikh, ok check that gist

There isn’t a built-in method in the scaffoldKey to directly check if the bottom sheet is open. However, when you open the bottom sheet using scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(), it returns a PersistentBottomSheetController. You can store this controller and use its closed getter to determine if the bottom sheet is still open. The controller also provides a close method to manually close the bottom sheet.
To achieve this, you can follow these steps:

Define a variable to hold the controller:

PersistentBottomSheetController? controller;


When opening the bottom sheet, assign the returned controller to this variable:

controller = _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showBottomSheet(
  (_) => Container(
    height: 200,
    color: Colors.grey,
  ),
);


Use the closed getter to listen for when the bottom sheet is closed and reset the controller to null:

controller?.closed.then((_) => controller = null);


To check whether the bottom sheet is open, you can simply check if the controller is null:

if (controller != null) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Bottom Sheet is open'),
    ),
  );
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Bottom Sheet is closed'),
    ),
  );
}


Full Example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MainApp(),
  ));
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  // Global key to access the ScaffoldState
  static final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PersistentBottomSheetController? controller;

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Open the bottom sheet and store the controller
                controller = _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showBottomSheet(
                  (_) => Container(
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                );

                // Listen for when the bottom sheet is closed and reset the controller
                controller?.closed.then((_) => controller = null);
              },
              child: const Text('Open Bottom Sheet'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => controller?.close(), // Close the bottom sheet if open
              child: const Text('Close Bottom Sheet'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();

                // Check if the bottom sheet is open and show a corresponding message
                if (controller != null) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Bottom Sheet is open'),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Bottom Sheet is closed'),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Check if Bottom Sheet is Open'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


i have 3 bottom sheets that are being presented.** so, it's not good choise to observe the status of each one of them through PersistentBottomSheetController.

@A-E Then, tbh with what we got I can't think of a better solution than having three controllers, one for each bottom sheet. Or you can have three bool variables instead to only store the open/close status of each bottom sheet.

@A-E Another good solution that follows my answer would be defining int openBottomSheetsCount = 0 and then do openBottomSheetsCount++ on every scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(), and openBottomSheetsCount-- inside each .closed.then(). Now you only need to check openBottomSheetsCount to see if its equals 0 to find out if any bottom sheet is open or not. It would work with even more than three bottom sheets.

these solutions are workaround solutions, i knew about it, but i'm looking for a straightforward way using the framework itself, for example in earlier versions of flutter there was a method called isBottomSheetOpen but it's deprecated and removed in the current latest version.
